# Rigorous proof of the convolution- Sum Representation of LTI Systems

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis

We've started learning LTI systems and I have confusion regarding the convolution sum representation of a system.

My problem stems from insufficient mathematical formalism in signals and systems introductory textbooks.

We have the discrete-time unit impulse function (or kronecker delta) $\delta[n]$:

$$\delta[n] = \begin{cases}
 1 \qquad & \text{if } n = 0,\\
 0 \qquad & \text{if } n \neq 0 \\
\end{cases} $$

then $x[n]$ can be represented as:

$$ x[n] = \sum_{k = -\infty}^{+\infty}x[k] \, \delta[n-k] $$

I'm not sure how infinity is defined here (obviously as a limit, but I couldn't find a book where it's mentioned.). However, I understand the equation intuitively.

Then, as a 'direct' result from linearity and time invariance:

$$ y[n] = \sum_{k = -\infty}^{+\infty}x[k] \, h[n-k] $$

Where $h[n-k]$ is the impulse response.

Now, everything makes sense intuitively when I think of infinity as a "large enough index". But formally, infinity is a limit, and linearity is defined for a finite number of terms.

How can this be proven rigorously using a formal definition of infinite sum?

Comment: How long would a given $x$ or $h$ have to be for these expressions to hold true?

Comment: So what is wrong with saying:

$$ x[n] = \lim_{K \to +\infty} \sum_{k = -K}^{+K}x[k] \, \delta[n-k] $$

?

Comment: To be honest, A large percentage of the people here are applied people. The limits are meant to contain the support of the signal and impulse response. For many if something works, it's rigorous enough.  Multivariate calculus and linear algebra is typically sufficient.  There is a famous quote by Richard Hamming that goes along the lines if  measure theory was required to design an airplane, you should get off of it.  You might get more action posting your question in Mathematics.

Comment: "and linearity is defined for a finite number of terms" then you're using a different definition of linearity than the one I learned.  The one I learned says that the system has to obey superposition for any input signal and any time.

Comment: if you are ok with the standard calculus introduction of **infinite series** (power series), Laurent or Taylor expansions, such as $$e^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{ x^n}{n!} $$ which include a sum infinite terms (with a possibility of divergence) without using the limit definition, then you should also be ok with the infinite sums you have in signal processing

Comment: I think I see the issue. A vector space is traditionally closed under finite addition "only". And the $\exp$ series, it stems from a topology, and is absolutely convergent.